# Python: Matplotlib Patches and Contour Plots

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there a way to make the filling of a circle transparent when using the PatchCollection? I plotted a circle, and I tried setting the facecolor to 'none', but it is covering the contour map that it is plotted on top of. I would like to see the outline of the circle with the contouring remaining visible behind it.

The stereonet was plotted using the mplstereonet-0.2 third-party software. Here is the part of the script where the image is plotted:

```
hold(True)



fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw = dict(projection = 'stereonet')) # Schmidt by default

cax = ax.density_contourf(strike, dip, measurement = 'poles')

ax.pole(strike, dip, 'k^', markersize = 3)
ax.grid(True)


patches = []
circle = Circle((0, 0), 0.5, facecolor = 'none', fill = False)
patches.append(circle)
p = PatchCollection(patches)
ax.add_collection(p)

cbar = fig.colorbar(cax, cmap = cm)
cbar.set_clim(0, 25)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem, but thank you to anyone that was possibly looking into this.

The solution:

```
    p = PatchCollection(patches, match_original = True)
```

This will make it so that the contour is seen behind the shape.

[image]

Comment: I was just about to respond. My comment would be that if you only plot 1 circle, avoid the whole PatchColection and add it direcly with:

    ax.add_artist(circle)

Comment: Nice. I was going to suggest using `ax.add_patch(circle)` which works fine (if you only have one patch there's no need to use a PatchCollection). Though, you should have really provided a minimal working example in your question.

Comment: Just FYI, you can also specify `facecolor='none'` when creating the `PatchCollection` (or use `p.set_facecolor`).  The reason that the default isn't to match the original patch when making a collection is that collections are commonly used to either speed up drawing of a bunch of almost identical artists or map some attribute such as facecolor to another scalar (e.g. color by `z`).  (On another side note, I didn't even know the `match_original` option existed. That's handy!)  As everyone else mentioned, for a single circle, just adding it directly is easier.  Good luck!